# Button below EditText is not visible when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, button, keyboard, visible

I have a form and a button below that should be visible when the keyboard is visible, but I somehow cannot manage that state.

1. In manifest in the activity I have:

   ```
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation"
   ```
2. the xml file looks like this.

   ```
   <com.myapp.components.NonInvasiveScrollView      
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"    
       android:fillViewport="true"> 

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scrollbars="none"
           android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"    
           android:paddingBottom="10dp"    
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <HorizontalScrollView 
               android:id="@+id/hor_scrollview"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_weight="1"          
               android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
               android:scrollbars="none"
               android:overScrollMode="never"
               android:paddingTop="15dp"
               >
               <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/vizual"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/vizual"                                
                   />            
           </HorizontalScrollView>

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

               <RadioGroup
                   android:id="@+id/add_tabs"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:weightSum="2" >

                   <com.funtasty.appool.components.SegmentedControlButton
                       android:id="@+id/mam_napad"
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:checked="true"                    
                       android:text="Mám nápad na aplikaci"
                       android:singleLine="true"                                                           
                       android:textSize="@dimen/smallText" />

                   <com.myapp.components.SegmentedControlButton
                       android:id="@+id/umim_tvorit"
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:checked="false"
                       android:singleLine="true"
                       android:text="Umím tvořit aplikace"                    
                       android:textSize="@dimen/smallText" />
               </RadioGroup>

               <ViewFlipper
                   android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@id/add_tabs"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/add_mam_napad"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical" >

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                            >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                               android:focusable="true"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_name" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/name"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:hint="Jméno a příjmení"
                               android:singleLine="true"
                               android:inputType="text"
                               android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:focusable="true"                            
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText"
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"                                                               
                               android:maxLines="1" />
                       </TableRow>

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                            >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_mail" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/email"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_weight="0"
                               android:hint="E-mail"
                               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"                        
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText"  
                               android:focusable="true"                        
                               android:maxLines="1" />
                       </TableRow>

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                           >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_bulb" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/message"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_weight="0"
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
                               android:gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText"
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"                            
                               android:inputType="textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine" 
                               android:maxLines="10"
                               android:focusable="true"
                               android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                               android:hint="Popiš svůj nápad" />
                       </TableRow>
                   </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/add_umim_tvorit"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="vertical" >

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                            >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_name" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/name_umim_tvorit"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_weight="0"
                               android:hint="Jméno a příjmení"
                               android:singleLine="true"
                               android:textIsSelectable="true"
                               android:inputType="text"
                               android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:focusable="true"
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText"                                           
                               android:maxLines="1" />
                       </TableRow>

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                            >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_mail" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/email_umim_tvorit"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_weight="0"
                               android:hint="E-mail"
                               android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                               android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText" 
                               android:focusable="true"                            
                               android:maxLines="1" />
                       </TableRow>

                       <TableRow
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/rowMarginTop"
                            >

                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                               android:src="@drawable/ico_bulb" />

                           <EditText
                               android:id="@+id/message_umim_tvorit"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_weight="0"
                               android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                               android:paddingLeft="10dp"     
                               android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                               android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
                               android:textSize="@dimen/bigText" 
                               android:textColor="@color/gray"
                               android:focusable="true"
                               android:inputType="textMultiLine"               
                               android:hint="Napiš něco o sobě" />
                       </TableRow>
                   </LinearLayout>
               </ViewFlipper>

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button_odeslat"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="48dp"

                   android:layout_below="@id/viewFlipper"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
                   android:gravity="center"          
                   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"
                   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/add_fragment_margin"                
                   android:background="@drawable/bg"
                   android:text="Odeslat"
                   android:textColor="@drawable/button_color"
                   android:focusable="true"
                   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                   android:enabled="false"

                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />
           </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>

   </com.myapp.components.NonInvasiveScrollView>
   ```

I don't get why the `softInputMode` does not work :/ I just want the button to be visible with the edittexts above the keyboards.

Comment: put the button above Edit Text, It will be visible

Comment: or to the right side of it like everyone else does.

Comment: that´s against UX desing, because first you fill in the form and only after that you click on a button

Answer (score 5):

In your manifest, for this activity, change windowSoftInputMode to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This will cause the layout to move up when the keyboard is shown, making the button visible.

Comment: I don't know what "NonInvasiveScrollView" is but try setting its layout_height to match_parent.

Comment: try to set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" @vandus

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
boolean checkKeyboard = false;

final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams cur_params = linearScroll.getLayoutParams(); //current layout params

final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activity_image_layout);

activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
       int margin =  activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight()-heightDiff;

        // screen height without keyboard layout
        if (heightDiff > 100) { 
            if(!checkKeyboard){
                // set new layout params  ...new 
                LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, margin);
                checkKeyboard = true;               
            }
        } else {
            // set first layout params cur_params
            layout.setLayoutParams(cur_params);
            checkKeyboard = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please, what should this activityRootView be in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole layout in a  instead of using a  for only an image. That will make sure you can scroll when the button is invisible behind your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

use in `Button` `->` `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`  its fixed your button position then scroll views and shows your button..

it may be helps you...